# How do I disable Expect100Continue if I use BizTalk to communicate with a webservice?

Tags: biztalk

An interface has as a requirement that we do not include an expect-100. (The documentation is assuming I will be using c# or php code to talk and has the code to not send the expect-100)

I quickly googled around a bit and found many topics on how to disable this when not using BizTalk and found multiple posts that would make me believe that BizTalk sends an expect-100 by default as well. ([BizTalk Data Services: Extended to bring management functions through IUpdatable](http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2010/06/biztalk-data-services-extended-to-bring-management-functions-through-iupdatable/) and [Adding Custom HTTP Headers to messages send via HTTP Adapter.](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/adding-custom-http-headers-to-messages-send-via-http-adapter/)). I have had trouble in finding someone trying to disable it.

Since I have found the C# code to disable it, would a solution be to create a custom pipeline component that disables this?

Comment: So is this web service requiring a pre-authentication like oAuth or similar?   If that is the case you want a End Point behavior rather than a Pipeline component as that sort of things tends to happen in the Adapter.

Comment: Also what Binding/Adapter are you using to connect to the web service?

Comment: Also have you tried sending to the webservice without trying to remove the Expect: 100-continue?  If so what happened?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I haven't actually started this Job, i received the 'documentation' from the customer and was asked to make an estimate on time. I have only done simple webservices myself with the WCF-BasicHttp type.

Comment: The documentation mentions that everything except the getStatus will require you to not include the expect-100 (Due to the size of the message) I am still trying to get a test version of the webservice that i could use without worry of messing up the other parties system.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing Expect: 100- continue in any trace to or from BizTalk using WCF.  I will say that it is very strange that they would have a dependency on not seeing this.  Either way, if WCF is sending it, you should be able to remove it with a behavior.  But, this isn't something I would worry about now since you'd have to do half the work to even fine out.  Here's where I say just try it and see what happens.

Comment: @Johns-305 I have succesfully made the call, so your answer was correct. Do i either remove this question or would you be willing to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something I would worry about.  I don't recall ever seeing Expect: 100- continue in any trace to or from BizTalk using WCF.

I will say that it is very strange that they would have a dependency on *not* seeing this. Either way, if WCF is sending it, you should be able to remove it with a Behavior.

You'll have to set this all up to even see if it's a problem.  Here's where I say *just try it and see what happens*.